# SSH key authentication not working

Tags: ssh, permissions, ubuntu-10.04, ssh-keys

I've a server running Ubuntu 10.04 (as a VM) to which I can't connect using ssh key authentication without being asked for the password. I've read a lot before posting but I really don't know what I'm missing.

My **.ssh** folder in the server has **700** for permissions and the **authorized keys** file has **600** for permissions. The result is like this:

```
drwx------ 2 myUser myUser 4096 Mar 26 12:15 .ssh
-rw------- 1 myUser myUser 426  Mar 26 12:15 authorized_keys
```

Checking */var/auth/auth.log*, I've been able to detect these 2 lines that are repeated every time I log in (and I'm asked for the password):

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/myUser.
Accepted password for myUser from myIP port 64916 ssh2
```

I think the configuration of the keys (content of **authorized_keys**, etc) is ok, because I've found that if I turn off **Strict Modes**, I can log in without being asked for the password, but I'm not sure about if this is secure and I want to have the system protected of intrusions.

Does anyone know what might be my problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StrictModes checks the home directory permissions not just the .ssh directory. As the man pages say:  This is normally desirable because novices sometimes accidentally leave their directory or files world-writable.

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/myUser.
```

Says it has a problem with the home directory permissions.

Comment: I just ran `chmod go-w ~/` and it solved the problem.